# How do I make an object turn black, when a movie clip animation turns black?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a light bulb movie clip, where it glows and burns out. I want everything in the scene to turn black when it does burn out. Like objects, movieclips, and arrays. When the light bulb comes back on, I want the objects to turn back to their original color. How do I do this?

Comment: You want arrays to turn black?

Comment: To be more specific, I am making a game where fireflies fall from the top. There is a light bulb in the center of the screen, and when the light bulb goes out I only want the fireflies light to light up. The fireflies are in an array

Comment: Your question is far too specific for StackOverflow. Without knowing the complete structure of your application and seeing code, we could not even begin to think about how to do what you are asking. I voted to close.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way would be to just create a black rectangle and add it to the stage when you want the lights to go out.

When you want the lights back, just remove it from the stage.

You could also adjust the alpha of that black rectangle over time or tween it to have it gradually turn black. When the rectangle has alpha set to 0, everything else's color will be as if the lights are on. Alpha set to 1, would be complete darkness.

Update - now that you have changed the question in the comments of the question by adding details that would have been helpful from the beginning :

You can use `ColorTransform` to change the color of your fireflies to black. Google that or search that on this site for detail.

Also, you can do this effect in the IDE by setting one frame as normal, and in another frame tint it black using a color effect on the properties panel. (Not sure what version of the IDE you have, it might be labeled differently in earlier versions)

Comment: To be more specific, I am making a game where fireflies fall from the top. There is a light bulb in the center of the screen, and when the light bulb goes out I only want the fireflies light to light up

Comment: "I want everything in the scene to turn black when it does burn out." - so, not everything in the scene ? Why not just ask - How do I turn a movieclip black ? everything else is irrelevant. right ? Also, the fireflies are not an Array, they are in an Array.